# Fade div in when at specifik location

Tags: scrolltop

I want to fade my header in when the scrolltop is at the div called:

```html
<div id="wieZijnWij" style="position:absolute; margin-top: -80px;z-index: 999"></div>
```

Now i found this code:

```jquery
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 768) {
        $(".introHeader").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $(".introHeader").stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
```

And it work, but it works when the scrolltop is at 768 px.
Can I code it so, that it only fades in when the scrolltop is at a specific div?

Comment: Please, does anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    a=$(".div").position();
});

$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > a.top ) {
        $(".div").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $(".div").stop().fadeOut();
}
```

Fixed it!